# Plone: dexterity content type default view template

Tags: plone, dexterity, plone-4.x

I created a new dexterity content type (named Report) using schema interface. Also I defined a custom view having a template report_view.pt.

I need some content from the original/default template to use in my custom template. Where can I find the code used for default view template of a dexterity content type?

Comment: https://community.plone.org/t/stack-exchange-plone-dexterity-content-type-default-view-template/4589

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/plone/plone.dexterity/blob/master/plone/dexterity/browser/configure.zcml

The default view for Dexterity content uses a WidgetsView and renders all widgets in display mode.

The standard view definition in browser/configure.zcml references the page template involved:

```
<browser:page
    for="..interfaces.IDexterityContent"
    name="view"
    class=".view.DefaultView"
    template="item.pt"
    permission="zope2.View"
    />
```

Additionally, the plone.app.dexterity package overwrites the default view for containerish content types with:

```
<browser:page
    for="plone.dexterity.interfaces.IDexterityContainer"
    name="view"
    class="plone.dexterity.browser.view.DefaultView"
    template="container.pt"
    permission="zope2.View"
    />
```